# Delete View References from View Controllers Swift iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How to automatically remove all references in an iOS Swift app(developed using XCode) from ViewControllers when deleting the View in a storyboard?

Comment: A trick to seek attention of people to answer your question is: Include Code in you question.

Comment: @iAhmed: Usually, I'd agree but I don't think this question is **about** code.

Comment: I agree this is less about code. But as you know people see colours in questions here most of the time. If they dont find colours they downvote questions. Opt is luck havent got yet :D 
@nidhimj20 references are handled automatically by ARC if u mean references. If you want to do it by yourself u can set any reference to nill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's not an automatic way to remove the reference within your code. Anyway, you can use the Connections inspector to see all the outlets and actions referring to your view and you can unlink them before actually removing the view from the storyboard. The rest is kind of code maintenance that I usually do by hand.